# How to convert Json Array to Java Array of Objects

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a json object which has following contents :

```
{
   "similarUserScores":[
      {
         "user":"u26",
         "score":0.6199970840986468
      },
      {
         "user":"u37",
         "score":0.5405403752816058
      },
      {
         "user":"u12",
         "score":0.523836143999991
      },
      {
         "user":"u24",
         "score":0.4990480549411648
      }
   ]
}
```

I need to convert it into java objects. So I created a java class to map this :

```
public class SimilarUserScores {

    private String user;

    private double score;

    public String getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(String user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public double getScore() {
        return score;
    }

    public void setScore(double score) {
        this.score = score;
    }

}
```

So how can I convert the above JSON to a list of java objects?

```
//Get Recommendations for this user
JsonObject recommendedUserJson  = PredictionIoClientHelper
                                       .getInstance().getRecommendedUser("u"+userId, limit);
if(recommendedUserJson != null) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String jsonString = recommendedUserJson.toString();
    SimilarUserScores[] recommendedUsers= gson.fromJson(jsonString, SimilarUserScores[].class);
}
```

I tried to use the above snippet however it did not worked.

Answer (score 4):

You have to initialize a `JSONObject` and an `ArrayList<SimilarUserScores>`.

Then you have to get the `JSONArray` and iterate over it.

For each iteration you set the data into the object and then append it to the output list. Here's an example of working code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

String s = "{\"similarUserScores\":[{\"user\":\"u26\",\"score\":0.6199970840986468}, ...

ArrayList<SimilarUserScores> objects = new ArrayList();
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(s);
JSONArray scores = obj.getJSONArray("similarUserScores");
for (int i = 0; i < scores.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject element = scores.getJSONObject(i);
    SimilarUserScores object = new SimilarUserScores();
    object.setUser(element.getString("user"));
    object.setScore(element.getDouble("score"));
    objects.add(object);
}
```

The previous code assumes that the JSON is in a `String` variable and that you have already defined `SimilarUserScores` class.
This code uses "JSON" library. If you are using maven, you can import it adding the following snippet in your pom.xml under the tag `<dependencies>`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20180130</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: @Paras can you please accept this answer if helped you?

Answer (score 1):

You need an wrapper around your `SimilarUserScores`.

Honestly, your inner class should be better named `UserScore`

```
public class SimilarUserScores {
    private List<UserScore> similarUserScores;
    // Getter setter
}

public class UserScore {

    private String user;

    private double score;
}
```

Now parse your json against `SimilarUserScores` class

Comment: Hi can you please describe how to parse it ?